# Android development Image Gallery path

Tags: android, image, path, gallery

I am working on app which should display all images from my sd card. it is gallery app but i cant make it to do it little weak in android 
it only get images from my mention path if i dont mention any path no images just root dir

```
String ExternalStorageDirectoryPath = Environment
.getExternalStorageDirectory()
 .getAbsolutePath();
String targetPath = ExternalStorageDirectoryPath + "/dir"; 
File targetDirector = new File(targetPath);
File[] files = targetDirector.listFiles();
for (File file : files){
myImageAdapter.add(file.getAbsolutePath());
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please explain what this means: " but i cant make it to do it little weak in android it only get images from my mention path". Please explain what you are trying to do and what is not working i.e. spell out exactly what you are looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you are trying to make an app that shows all the images in your device and the current code shows only the mentioned directory.

use Intent to search the image type files available in your device.

```
Intent imageIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
imageIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
imageIntent.setType("image/*");
imageIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
startActivityForResult(imageIntent , READ_REQUEST_CODE); // set READ_REQUEST_CODE to 42 in your class
```

process your results in the onActivityResult() method.

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

if (requestCode == READ_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {

        Uri uri = null;
        if (data != null) {
            uri = data.getData();
            Log.i(TAG, "Uri: " + uri.toString());
            showImage(uri);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With this two lines of code you will pick the images stored into the default gallery directory:

```
File picturesDirectory = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
File[] listFiles = picturesDirectory.listFiles();
```

If you need to search into ALL sdcard use this recursive method:

```
public static void allFiles(File root, List<File> list){
   for (File node : root.listFiles())
   {
       if (node.isDirectory())
           allFiles(node, list);
       else list.add(node);
   }
}
```

Then call this method like that:

```
List<File> allSdCardFiles = new ArrayList<File>();
allFiles(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), allSdCardFiles);

/*now your list has all the sdcard files, use it like you want*/
```

Anyway, I think you understand this is a very heavy operation, so be sure you really need that (after that you also have to check the extension of your files to check if they are images, because this recursive method returns ALL sdcard files);

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method to get the default Gallery Path

```
private static String getDefaultGalleryPath() {
    return Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM + "/";
}
```

**What is [DIRECTORY_DCIM](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#DIRECTORY_DCIM)?**

The traditional location for pictures and videos when mounting the device as a camera.